# Figure is not appearing in LaTex document

Tags: tables, floats

I have a question regarding latex tables and figures. This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Template Master Thesis/Figures/conceptual model.png}
    \caption{Conceptual model}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

Once I remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` my image is appearing. But with the current code, the image is not appearing. I want to add a caption to the image but I cannot do that If I don't use `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`. The same applies to adding a table.

Can someone help me in making this code work, by displaying the figure with caption in my document?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Regarding "the image is not appearing": is the image not showing up at all or just not where you would expect it to show up?

Comment: `figure` and `table` are floating environments which means they not necessarily appear in the pdf exactly where you pleaced them in the input. You can influence the positioning of floats  (See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)).

Comment: If you absolutely do not want images to float but need a caption nevertheless (however, be warned about large white spaces if an image does not fit onto the remainder of a page), you can use `\captionof{figure}{...}` or `\captionof{table}{...}` to add captions to images and tabulars outside of `figure` od `table` environments.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for your response! I see that both my figure and table appear at the end of my document. But  I want it in the text... I used your tip of this page "How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?" When using \begin{table}[h] it still appears at the end of my document

Comment: @leandriis I used \captionof{figure}{...} and this works! Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Regarding: "it still appears at the end": Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: ` \begin{table}[h] ` (`figure` would be more natural than `table`) makes going to the end quite likely as it specifies that the float may not be placed at toe top or bottom of a page or on a page that only has floats (no t b or p) so latex doesn't have many options (in fact usually it gives a warning and change sit to `[ht]` to give itself at least a chance to position the figure)